# How to make a resizable QLabel which can be auto-resize by the user

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel

I have a one `QLabel` which contain one `QPixmap` image, I want to make this label resizable so that the user can resized it.
I know to accomplish this I need to create my own label inheriting from `QLabel`, I have done that but don't know what to do now, Please help me, It's important.

My code:

```
in header:
class resizeLabel: public QLabel
{
public:
resizeLabel(parent):{}
};
in cpp:
resizeLabel *rl= new resizeLabel(this);
QPixmap image(path);
rl->setPixmap(image);
rl->show();
```

I don't know how to make this image on the label resizable, so that user can resize it.

Comment: Yes I want to resize this ```QLabel``` from the bottom right corner and No I don't want this to grow and shrink with the application window. Please help me, Is it not possible to make the ```QLabel``` resizable?

Comment: sorry but it seems very complex and i don't think it is much helpful but before asking the question here I have searched overall the google and I have seen that it's possible but no clear answer was found there that's why i asked here, One place i saw he was using ```QSizeGrip```, If you know how to use that to accomplish my task then please help me unless it's all will be waste.

Comment: I solved it no thanks.